# Linking an existing activity to a new view in same stream (A view of same name was deleted accidentally)

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Accidentally I deleted `viewA` having activity `actA`. Now I could find the activity `actA` still existed in the stream.

I could again create a view with same name `viewA` but when I do `cleartool lsact` it does not list any activity.
I am able to do `setact viewA` manually but I want to link this activity to the `viewA` so that when I issue `cleartool lsact` my activity `actA` should be listed by default.

Comment: I'll put an answer in a few hours, but try at least an `lsact -in yourStream@\yourPVob` (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm) The activity should still be there.

Comment: @VonC I can find it in stream and also set the activity by issuing `cleartool setact` manually but it never shows when I set the view followed by issuing `cleartool lsact` or `cleartool lsact -cact`. Would like to bring to your notice that I deleted a view with same name earlier

Comment: If you can find the activity, create any new view, and set that activity to said new view with cleartool setact (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)

Comment: That's exactly what I have done but the need is it shud be exactly like the old one i.e. `ct lsact` should list activities associated with the view. Some internal tool checks this by issuing `cleartool lsact`

Comment: For that, you need to be in the view in which you have associated the activit.

Comment: Doe's there exist any command to associate an activity to this view of same name ? or I will have to settle with the `ct setact ` manually

Comment: setact is better, and is done only once. Then your scritps will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That activity can still be listed with [`cleartool lsact`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm):

```
cleartool lsact -in yourStream@/vobs/yourPVob
```

The best course of action, once you have create a similar UCM view on the same stream, is to associate your activity back to that new view with [`cleartool setact`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)

```
cd /path/to/new/UCM/view/vobs/myvob
cleartool setact  anActivity@/vobs/yourPVob
```